# Change active tabs (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have array of tabs.

Here is the code

```
const navTabs: ITab[] = [
    { Name: allTab, Icon: 'gs-all', Selected: true },
    { Name: sources.corporateResources, Icon: 'gs-resources', Selected: false },
    { Name: sources.employee, Icon: 'gs-people', Selected: false },
    { Name: sources.services, Icon: 'gs-services', Selected: false },
    { Name: sources.information, Icon: 'gs-docs', Selected: false },
    { Name: sources.tableau, Icon: 'gs-tableau', Selected: false },
];
```

In method activate tab I change `selected: true` tab to false and than I find tab by name and set it to `selected: true`

Here is code

```
public activateTab(name: TabName): void {
    this.activeTab = name;
    this.navTabs.find(x => x.Selected === true).Selected = false;
    this.navTabs.find(x => x.Name === name).Selected = true;
    // console.log(navTabs);
}
```

Can I make somehow this in one operation?

```js
this.navTabs.find(x => x.Selected === true).Selected = false;
this.navTabs.find(x => x.Name === name).Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop over them all (`forEach`) and then set `Selected` to the condition where you check the `name`:

```js
const navTabs = [
  { Name: 'foo', Icon: 'gs-all', Selected: true },
  { Name: 'foo', Icon: 'gs-resources', Selected: false },
  { Name: 'foo', Icon: 'gs-people', Selected: false },
  { Name: 'bar', Icon: 'gs-services', Selected: false },
  { Name: 'foo', Icon: 'gs-docs', Selected: false },
  { Name: 'foo', Icon: 'gs-tableau', Selected: false },
];

const nameToMatch = 'bar';

navTabs.forEach(o => o.Selected = (o.Name === nameToMatch));

console.log(navTabs);
```